# How physically does blowing air in front of a piece of paper move the piece of paper?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

Suppose you stand a piece of paper upright on a table and then stand a few inches away parallel to the paper and blow through a straw.  The paper will move towards the air stream.  My question is: Why does this happen?

I am **not interested** in the answer

> "Because there's a higher air pressure behind the paper and a lower air pressure in front of the paper due to the faster air stream and bernoulli's equation says blah blah blah".

I am specifically asking about the cause-and-effect chain that starts with a stream of air particles moving in front of the paper and ends with the paper moving towards the air stream.

My explanation:

1. Air is blown from the opening of the straw.
2. The stream of air particles emitted pushes the atmospheric air in its path along the path of the air stream.
3. As the front of the air stream and the sides of the air stream continue to move along the stream path, the closely surrounding air particles move into the stream and are pushed along the stream by the other stream particles.
4. This results in a "hole volume" surrounding the air stream where the atmospheric air close to the stream used to be.
5. A section of the hole volume between the stream and the paper propagates away from the stream and moves towards the paper.
6. Once the section of hole volume reaches the paper, we have the situation where the opposite side of the paper experiences more air particle collisions than the side exposed to the section of hole volume.
7. Due the higher number of collisions on the opposite side of the paper, the paper moves in the direction of the collisions which is towards the air stream.

Is this correct?  If this is incorrect or incomplete.  Which step is wrong or needs additional steps?

Comment: To the downvoter: please provide a reason for the downvote so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

the air parcels flowing over the convex upper surface of the curled piece of paper tend to follow the curved paper surface, which is sagging downwards. the air parcels departing the paper thereby have had their momentum vectors tipped slightly downwards, representing a change in the direction of those vectors. The time derivative of a momentum vector has the units of *force*, meaning that the curved paper had to have exerted a net force upon those air parcels while they were passing by- and that means the air parcels exerted a net reaction force on the paper surface.

That reaction force tends to pull up on the piece of paper.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however I am not sure I understand what you're talking about.  The paper described in the first sentence of my question is standing upright and has no specified curvature and could be concave, convex, or neither of these.  Additionally, since the paper is standing upright it isn't sagging at all. Blowing across the paper as described in the experiment in the second sentence results in the paper moving forwards towards the air stream blowing in front of it so I am not sure what you're talking about when you say the paper is being pulled upwards.

Comment: If you can update your answer to address the discrepancies it would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not know how. I answered the question as I understood it.